# Tensorflow begginer examples that not use MNIST

Tags: java, python, tensorflow, keras

I have question, maybe silly one but we will see.

I want to build simply [k-NN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm) model in Tensorflow (or Keras, we will see) and use it in my Java project, but its not a case.

My data will looks like this:

```
data: [
    {id: 1, distance: [111, 222, 333] }, 
    {id: 1, distance: [222, 111, 333] },
    {id: 1, distance: [333, 444, 555] },
    {id: 2, distance: [111, 555, 666] },
    ... and so on 
    ... indexes of distance array are my features
]
```

What i want to do is to classify new `data` object based on `distance` that i will calculate in my model, and the same model will tells me with `accurate`, for which `id` distance will be classify.

And here my question start. Could you tell me, how to load very simple datasets to tensorflow not from file, but from code? On the interenet there is a lot examples, but all is based on MNIST or other big datasets that are provided by big Neural networks or CNNs.

I dont find the basics that im asking for, thats why im asking in Stack.

Thanks for any advices

Ps. Yes, i need to use Tensorflow/Keras. Because i want and i can import model to Java from it. And i know KNN alghoritm because i written it in Java and C# before based on Manhattan and Euklidian distance. Now, i want to use ML/AI library to do this.

**EDIT:**

In static-typed languages like C++, C#, Java writing alghoritm like KNN is pretty simple (and its pretty fast). I cant belive there is no simple examples to use TF/Keras on the internet, simpler that MNIST datasets

The simple one that i found is based on `iris.dataset` but still, data is loded from pre-build datasets from TF.

```
http://marubon-ds.blogspot.com/2017/09/knn-k-nearest-neighbors-by-tensorflow.html
```

The biggest problem that i have to understand is to load simple data, as i mentioned above

Answer (score 3):

If I've understood your question correctly, you need to import your dataset into Tensorflow framework. To do this you can convert your data into CSV file and use this [Tensorflow doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets#consuming_csv_data).

Comment: But i want to avoid saving anything to csv, because user will input new datas. Every time he will pass data to program, i need to save and read CSV to use it in TF? Nonsense

Answer (score 1):

If someone looking pretty easy examples with TensorFlow, i think this `github` repo is related to our needs. Maybe someone will share his code with simple examples? I think that this topic on SO will be open, i wont mark answers so anyone can post his code or link to simple codes

[TensorFlow Cookbook](https://github.com/nfmcclure/tensorflow_cookbook)